# Alamofire PUT isn't working

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm Using Xcode 7 (7A220) and Alamofire 2.0.2 Carthage installed.

```
let parameters = ["briefDes": briefDes.text, "jobDetail": detail.text, "skill": skillsTF.text]
Alamofire.request(.PUT, "http://localhost:2403/postedjob?id=\(jobId.text)", parameters: parameters)
```

error:

> Alamofire was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly;
>   variables may not be available.

Comment: print your url and check (jobId.text) is optional or not

Comment: Thank you very much.! :D

Comment: @ImmaKillYa Suggest improving the question title and then answering your question below about the optional / unwrapping etc.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related to this:

Just incase anyone else is getting: error: Alamofire was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.

I was getting that error when constructing a URL for google geo services. I was appending a street address to the end of the URL WITHOUT encoding the street address itself first. 
My Solution:

```
var streetAdress = "123 fake street, new york, ny"
var escapedStreetAddress = streetAddress.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

let url = "(self.baseUrl)&address=(escapedAddress!)"
```

That fixed it for me! It didn't like that the address had spaces and commas, etc.

Hoping this can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3

The latest Syntax for POST Method is

```
let strUrl = "Your URL here"
    let parameter:Parameters = ["user_id":"2","isdelete": "0" ,"status":"0","page":pageindex ,"limit":"9"]
    Alamofire.request(strUrl, method : .post, parameters: parameter).responseJSON{response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
            if let innerDict = dict["orders"]{

                self.array.addObjects(from: innerDict as! [Any]);

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tblView.reloadData()
                    self.refresh.endRefreshing()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here The Parameters are also passed

> Note:- If in case no parameters are needed to be passed You can simply
>   Remove that from the **Alamofire.request** method

Hope This may be useful For future References

Thanks